# How magento 2 default content scheduling work programmatically

Tags: magento2, event-observer, cron, schedule, content

what is the logic behind the content scheduling in magento 2.

1. Using cron ?
2. using event observer ?

Answer (score 0):

- Content scheduling in general involves the use of a scheduling mechanism and event handling.
- A scheduling mechanism, such as cron jobs, is used to trigger actions at predefined intervals.
- Event observers are utilized to listen for specific events and execute custom logic accordingly.
- In the case of content scheduling, a scheduling mechanism can periodically check for scheduled content and trigger the appropriate actions based on the specified time.
- Event observers can listen for content-related events and apply scheduling logic to publish or unpublish the content accordingly.